# What exactly are Static Constructor in C#?

Tags: c#

I have couple of question regarding Static Constructor in C#.

1. What exactly are Static Constructor and how they are different from non-static Constructor.
2. How can we use them in our application ?

****Edited

```
public class Test
{
    // Static constructor:
    static Test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Static constructor invoked.");
    }

    public static void TestMethod()
    {
       Console.WriteLine("TestMethod invoked.");
    }
}

class Sample
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Test.TestMethod();
    }
}
```

Output : 
Static constructor invoked.
TestMethod invoked. 
So, this means that static constructor will be called once. if we again call  Test.TestMethod(); static constructor won't invoke.

---

Any pointer or suggestion would be appreciated
 '

Thanks

Comment: For example, you're using implicitly generated static constructors every time you're initialising a static field.

Comment: @SK-logic: <terminology-nitpick>You're not using an implicitly generated static constructor in that situation: you're using a type initialiser. There's no such thing as an implicit static constructor. A class either has an explicit static constructor or no static constructor.</terminology-nitpick>

Comment: Check out the output of ildasm /text for any class with static fields initialised with some values - you'll see an implicitly generated static constructor there.

Comment: @SK-logic: No you won't, you'll see a type initialiser. Static constructors are a C# concept, and a type either has an *explicit* static constructor or none at all. Any static field initialisation, along with any logic from the static constructor (if there is one) is performed by the type initialiser.

Comment: ".method private hidebysig specialname rtspecialname static       void  .cctor() cil managed" - exactly the same signature and properties as for a C#-generated static constructor.

Comment: @LukeH, why don't you try this ildasm output? If you specify an explicit C# static constructor, its code will be MERGED into an implicitly generated one. "Type initializer" is just another name of a static constructor. There's always only one such constructor in any class.

Comment: @SK-logic: I did mention that this was a terminology nitpick, didn't I? A C# type *either* has an explicit static constructor *or* no static constructor; there's no such thing as an implicit static constructor. The C# compiler transforms that source code into IL; if the C# source code contains *either* a static constructor *or* static fields initialised in their declaration then that logic will be compiled into the generated type-initialiser.

Comment: Yes, I see. I've been insisting that 'static constructor' is an IL concept, not a C# concept. 'Type initializer' is just an alias.

Comment: But probably you're right: ECMA-335 does not call it explicitly a 'constructor'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Static constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) are constructors that are executed only **ONCE** when the class is loaded. Regular (non-static) constructors are executed every time an object is created.

Take a look at this example:

```
public class A
{
     public static int aStaticVal;
     public int aVal;

     static A() {
         aStaticVal = 50;
     }

     public A() {
         aVal = aStaticVal++;
     }
}
```

And consider this code:

```
A a1 = new A();
A a2 = new A();
A a3 = new A();
```

Here, `static` constructor will be called **first** and only **once** during the execution of the program. While regular constructor will be called three times (once for each object instantiation).

`static` constructors are usually used to do initialization of static fields for example, assigning an initial value to static fields.. Do keep in mind that you will only be able to access `static` members (methods, properties and fields) on `static` constructors.

If you need to "execute the static constructor multiple times", you can't do that. Instead, you can put the code you want to run "multiple times" in a static method and call it whenever you need. Something like:

```
public class A {
    public static int a, b;
    static A() {
         A.ResetStaticVariables();
    }
    public static void ResetStaticVariables() {
        a = b = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Static constructors don't take access modifiers. Should just be `static A() {...}` See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: @Pablo: No problem. It does look and feel unnatural to not specify access mods for this case.

Comment: @Paul very well explained :) Thanks !! One more thing we can't execute static constructors again after class is loaded or at any point of time in runtime right?

Comment: @Monu: right. Runtime will execute the static constructor for you. It's never the case that you will call the constructor yourself. You can write a static method if you need to call it later on the execution of your program.

Comment: @Monu: updated the answer with a little example of what I told you w.r.t. calling static constructors multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

You use them the same way you use instance constructors - to set default values. Only in this case you'll be initializing static fields, so static constructors get executed only once.

Be aware that the code in static constructor won't be executed until the first call to the class was made.

Comment: Not until the first call - but until the class is loaded. A static field access will also trigger it.

Comment: @SK-Logic yes, that's what I meant. MSDN quote to clear things up: "A static constructor is called automatically to initialize the class before the first instance is created or any static members are referenced."

Answer (score 1):

it runs when class is loaded.

It will print :
{

1. hi from static A
2. A

}

```
public class A{
  static A{
     print("hi from static A");
  }

  public A() {
    print("A");
  }

  main() {
      new A();
  }
}
```